# Cannot restart mysql after setting bind-address

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have set up mysql on my server. I am trying to remotely access mysql from my mac via Codeigniter. I have set the bind-address to my server IP. However, I cannot restart mysql after setting the bind-address.

The server and my Mac are sharing the same IP(ie: I used router). Is that the reason why that bind-address is not able to pin the IP. Thus, it cannot restart?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the bind address needs to be the local address, not the NAT'd external IP address.

Comment: How am I going to make a connection?